# java string add comma become array

Tags: java, arrays

```
String items = "bookcupdoll";
```

I want to add a comma in items variable like below:

```
book,cup,doll
```

How should I make the string become an array?

Comment: And how do you determine where to split?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to convert a string to an array...
There is a handy method called "split(String separator)"

If the string looks like : String items = "book,cup,doll";

you can use it like this

```
String[] array = items.split(",");
```

And you will end up with an array of size 3 with the 3 different elements.